# Credit increase hurt loan chances?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

Objectives:

- Continue to purchase 1-2 rental properties a year
- Keep enough revolving credit for large emergency's
- Continue to pay off credit balance each month in order to avoid interest charges.
- Have highest cash back my bank offers.

Current factors:

- Expenses to income monthly is 45%
- Debt to income annually is ~32%
- Credit card debt is cleared monthly
- All three credit scores above 750

Situation:

I noticed my bank offered a cash back card that would get me .5% more if I got it. When I applied the bank offered me another $20k in revolving credit at an apr of 12.9% (which I requested they review to get down to 11.9%). If accepted my total available credit between my two cards at this bank would be $30k. Now I only have one credit card currently and the balance never exceeds what I can't cover in a single month. Usually 20%. My question is two fold.

1. Will it hurt my credit if I accept this new card?
2. Will it hurt my ability to continue getting home loans if I accept this new card?

We are assuming that my spending will remain a constant so my credit utilization would drop to 5% I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help your credit score to get the card.  30% of your credit score is calculated based on credit utilization.  you want to make sure you are only using about 25% of your available credit.  You will get dinged a bit for a age of credit history and credit inquiry count.

So for both of your questions the answer would be no.

Comment: The common number is 1-19% for ideal utilization. He already applied (credit inquiry ding), but you are correct, accepting the card hits his history age average.

Comment: Okay, this is what my gut was telling me but I'm not super versed with it so I wanted to ask. Thank you both for the input